# Custom ostream prints only last string of `<<` chain

Tags: c++, ofstream, ostream

I'm trying to implement a class with a custom stream operator, and inherits from it in order to have a base class and a derived one with different streams. Then I overload the `<<` operator for using stored `ostream`.

This is a working sample of the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>#
#include <fstream>

class Sink {
public:
    Sink() {
        m_stream = std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>(new std::ostream(std::cout.rdbuf()));
    };

    template<typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(const T& obj) {
        return *m_stream;
    }

protected:

    std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> m_stream;
};

class FileSink : public Sink {
public:

    FileSink() {
        m_stream = std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>(new std::ofstream("file.txt"));
    }
};

int main() {
    Sink s;
    FileSink fs;
    s << "First console string " << "second console string";
    fs << "First file string " << "second file string";
    return 0;
}
```

With the `Sink class` I write on console, with `FileSink` on a file.

The problem is that with this code I print only last string of every instruction.

In the console I see following output:

```
second console string
```

while in the file I can see this output:

```
second file string
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I print the expected output?

Comment: A good example for abusing std::unique_ptr (a simple pointer would be right here)

Comment: @DieterLücking What is a raw pointer advantage?

Comment: @DieterLücking if Sink class owns the pointer, why not use a unique_ptr? Otherwise, you need have a customized copy or move constructor, and a destructor

Comment: .... that is the abuse: sink does not own anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator<<` does nothing and returns `std::ostream&`. Then you apply `std::ostream::operator<<` to that `std::ostream&`. Expected thing!

Standard way to do what you want:

```
template<typename T>
Sink & Sink::operator<<(const T& obj) {
    *m_stream << obj;
    return *this;
}
template<typename T>
FileSink & FileSink::operator<<(const T& obj) {
    *m_stream << obj;
    return *this;
}
```

To prevent code duplication you can use inheritance. It may duplicate `std::stream` inheritance scheme, I think. : )

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(const T& obj) {
    *m_stream << obj;    // you missed this
    return *m_stream;
}
```

Also, you can define operator<< as a non-member function.

```
template <typename T> 
Sink& operator<<(Sink &sink, const T &obj) {
    *(sink.m_stream) << obj;
    return sink;
}
```

and make it a friend of Sink:

```
class Sink {
    template <typename T>
    friend Sink& operator<<(Sink &sink, const T &obj);
    // other code.
}
```